# Table head match specific design

Tags: css, tailwind-css

today I am working on a table design
design lady wanted a table like this
[design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yyid.png)

and I was able to make it look like this
[my-implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aWJe.png)

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    #header-body {
    display: flex;
    /* establish flex container */
    flex-direction: row;
    /* default value; can be omitted */
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    /* default value; can be omitted */
    justify-content: space-between;
    /* switched from default (flex-start, see below) */
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  <script>
    tailwind.config = {
      theme: {
        extend: {
          colors: {
            'me-black': '#4a4a49',
            'me-gray': '#58585b',
            'me-gray-2': '#929497',
            'me-bg': '#f3f4f2'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body class="bg-me-bg">
<section class="container mx-auto max-w-6xl bg-white px-9 h-screen border-x-2">
  <div class="pt-6 relative grid place-items-center min-h-2xl" id="header-body">
    Search (text should be distanced from edge like this)
  </div>
  <div class="pt-6 relative min-h-2xl">
    <div class="border-y border-me-gray-2">
      <table class='mx-auto w-full rounded-lg bg-white divide-y divide-me-gray overflow-hidden'>
        <thead class="bg-white">
        <tr class="text-white text-left">
          <th class="text-xl font-roboto font-bold text-me-black px-6 py-4 flex items-center"> Name
            <svg class="w-5 h-5 text-me-black" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                 fill="currentColor">
              <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                    d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z"
                    clip-rule="evenodd" />
            </svg>
          </th>
          <th class="text-xl font-roboto font-bold text-me-black px-6 py-4 w-44 "> Date created </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <colgroup  style="border: none;"> <!-- You set table columns here -->
          <col class="w-64"> <!-- 1. table column -->
          <col > <!-- 2. table column -->
        </colgroup>
        <tbody class="divide-y divide-me-gray">
        <tr>
          <td class="px-6 py-4">
            <div class="flex items-center space-x-3">
              <div>
                <p class="font-bold text-me-black my-2"> Protocol1 </p>
                <p class="text-me-gray text-sm font-roboto "> [Normal text] Suspendisse nec libero id ligula mollis ullamcorper quis vitae dui. Mauris vel. Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit...
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td class="px-6 py-4">
            <p class="text-xl font-roboto font-medium text-black">1.3.2019 - v6</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

here is an [example here](https://jsfiddle.net/pu8621af/)

Header is the worst, I just am unable to make it look like the design wants (and design is strict sadly), I don't know how to make lines above and below the header match the whole div and how to make this thin double line below the header

Thanks for Anwsering and Best Regards

Comment: _"here is an [example here](https://jsfiddle.net/adamwathan/z5pscdmz/)"_ - that appears to show something _completely_ different (some sort of user profile card), than your two screenshots ...?

Comment: oh, you are right, I forgot to hit save in jsfiddle and it didn't save the example, repaired the link now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be able to solve your double thin line problem using the new [TailwindCSS 3.1](https://tailwindcss.com/blog/tailwindcss-v3-1) utilities: `border-separate` and `border-spacing-y-1`

n.b. I would not worry too much about the line above the header, and suggest you use a `DIV` with and style the border.

Getting a result like the below, which seems to be in tune with your requirements.

For some extra love, find an
[example result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVxYe.png) and a [Tailwind Playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/GtZy6ODg5Y) to see the two utilities in action.